# How to store textbox value in multiple list in infopath form?

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I have 3 list with name list1, list2 and list 3, I'm trying to save data in these list using InfoPath form.

I have created following form.

[image]

I'm trying to save the title in all those lists, is it possible?

If yes then how?

Answer (score 1):

Create D**ata connection** to Retrieve data from **List1 , List2, List3**

[image]

1. On Button click write rule, Select rule type - Action
2. In Rule select Action Set field value

[image]

[image]

In above Image Field represent : Title column of List1

[image]
Write Two more action of **Set filed value** in same rule

Finally your rule look like this 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by creating a multiple Submit data rules for multiple data connection as the following

- in InfoPath > at Data Tab > add a data connection to submit data for all 3 lists. (one by one)

[image]

- then click on the button > From the above ribbon > add rule > `submit data` > and select the data connection of the first list .

[image]

- In the same button > add a new rule with `submit data` for the second list.
- repeat the same steps for the third list.
- Save and publish .